# autocomplete not working on atom reinstall

Tags: html, ubuntu, atom-editor

I have just reinstalled atom on my ubuntu 18.04 lts.
Earlier on writing HTML and clicking enter, the basic structure of HTML document was automatically completed by atom.
But after reinstalling I couldn't find that feature.
I don't remember whether I had installed any package for it in an earlier version or it was already available.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved
Actually, the reason for this problem was the conflict with the TabNine package which I installed earlier... Uninstalling it resolved the issue.